# Mute Google Meet's audio completely without muting the participants

Tags: google-meet

In the Google Meet app, I want to watch the presentation of the meeting, but I don't want to *hear* anything. I can't just mute people because that will mute them for other participants.

I can't seem to find an output mute control or volume control in the app itself. I tried turning the volume all the way down on my Android device, but the volume slider won't go all the way to the bottom. Even if I set my device to silent, it doesn't seem to affect Google Meet.

How can I mute Google Meet's audio *output* completely? If it matters, the device is a Samsung Galaxy Tab A 10.1 (2016) (SM-T580).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:
Use Companion mode for hybrid learning & collaboration - Google Meet Help
https://support.google.com/meet/answer/11295507

I tried opening a meeting in the app with a link like:
**https://meet.google.com/abc-defg-hij?companion=1**
and that let me turn the volume all the way down.  If that doesn't work for you, you might check the icon under the volume for more volume controls.

When I want to screen record a meeting on a desktop, I just mute the mic, and use an external display for the speaker device which I also mute.  A Bluetooth earbud, wired headset, or wireless speaker with volume control, might do the job as well on a phone.  Since this article came up when I did a search like how to come in to a Google Meet muted, I thought having this answer with the url argument (parameter or query string) "?companion=1" here which works on all platforms might be handy.

Answer (score 0):

As of January 2024, the Google Meets app (v221.0.x, earliest version unknown) supports muting the audio output.

On the top bar, besides the meeting code, there's an icon to control the audio output. One of the options is to mute the audio output.

[image]